# Change the nav-item background color not working

Tags: html, css

I want to change the background color of the active nav-item and of any nav-item hovered to "chartreuse" (just a color to test).

I've tried love of things but it's not working, why?

Not even using `!important`.

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/abNQXLg

CSS:

```
/* NAVBAR TOP */

#top-navbar {
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
}

.navbar-nav > .active > a {
  color: aqua;
  background-color: chartreuse;    
}
.nav-item > a:hover {
  color: aqua;
}
#navbarCollapse {
  margin-left: 1%;
}

#navbarCollapse ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-link {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}

/* start update */

nav ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding: 3px;
}

#navbarCollapse ul {
  padding-top: 10px
}

#navbarCollapse ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

nav {
  position: relative
}

nav form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the color of active nav-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743102/changing-the-color-of-active-nav-item)

Comment: No, I've look into it, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target the active nav-item like this:

```
.nav-item.active > a{

}
```

Then you can add css styling into it.
Before you weren't selecting the element properly.

What you desired:

```
.nav-item.active > a {
  color: aqua;
}

.nav-item > a:hover {
  background-color: chartreuse;    
}
```

See codepen: https://codepen.io/koder613/pen/ZEWNEgw?editors=1100

Comment: Not working. Have you tried this on the Codepen code?

Comment: @OmarGonzales You need to add the `active` class to one of the `nav-item`'s, then it will work: https://codepen.io/koder613/pen/ZEWNEgw?editors=1100

Comment: It works on active item, but not when hovering on others?

Comment: @OmarGonzales I updated my codepen, does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

I added active class on your second li to show how it looks like.

But more or less you should set your changing color in active class like:

```
.active{
  background-color: red;
}
.active:hover > a{
  color: yellow !important;
}
```

Like this both color will change when mouse is going hover your li with active class. And You add important where you want to make it stronger.

Pretty much duplicate of: [Changing the color of active nav-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743102/changing-the-color-of-active-nav-item)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";

  $('ul > li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul > li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
/* NAVBAR TOP */

#top-navbar {
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
}

.navbar-nav > .active > a {
  color: aqua;
  background-color: chartreuse;    
}
.active{
  background-color: red;
}
.nav-item.active:hover > a{
  color: yellow !important;
}
.nav-item > a:hover {
  color: aqua;
}
#navbarCollapse {
  margin-left: 1%;
}

#navbarCollapse ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-link {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}

/* start update */

nav ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding: 3px;
}

#navbarCollapse ul {
  padding-top: 10px
}

#navbarCollapse ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

nav {
  position: relative
}

nav form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <!--MENU SUPERIOR-->
    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top" id="top-navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"
                aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <!-- <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span> -->
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">   
                    <i class="fas fa-bars" style="color:#fff; font-size:28px;"></i>
                </span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto mt-0" href="/"><img src="/static/img/logos/elim-palmera-la-central-fondo-blanco.png" width="25px"
                height="30px"></a> 

            
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Inicio</a>
                    </li>

                    
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a href="/iglesias/" class="nav-link" >Iglesias</a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/doctrina/" class="nav-link" >Doctrina</a>
                    </li>
                    

                </ul>

            </div>
            <form class="form-inline ml-auto mt-3">
                
                <span class="text-white">Hola, ogonzales.</span>
                <a href="/salir/" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Salir</a>
                
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Yes, but how to change active class to currenct nav-item section programatically?

Comment: @OmarGonzales I guess add the jQuery in the link I set in duplicate and you can see that it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

To change the background color of the active nav-item. Call the navbar-nav class as it is in your ul tag as shown.

```html
<div class="collapse navbar" id="navbarCollapse">
<!-- Call the navbar-nav class in the ul tag -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Inicio</a>
                    </li>

                    
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/iglesias/" class="nav-link" >Iglesias</a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/doctrina/" class="nav-link" >Doctrina</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

And the following will show the "chartreuse" color when you hover over the nav-items.

`.nav-item > a:hover { color: aqua; background-color: chartreuse;   }`

Comment: Glen it is not working on the Code Snippet you've posted.

Comment: Try amend the your original code and insert the snippets I posted. I tried on **Codepen** it did work.